# Why localhost:8000 doesn't work, while ...:8000/test works fine on symfony?

Tags: php, symfony

Im completely new to Symfony so please bear with me. Im trying to configure my controller to atleast get a working webpage. I created a new Symfony project and started my server. After writing some code into `MyController`

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Controller;

use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

 class MyController
{
 /**
 * @Route("/test")
 */
 public function numberAction()
 {
    $prankBro= "Its just a prank bro";

    return new Response($prankBro);
 }
}
```

After trying to access `localhost:8000` I get a fatal 404 error: `No route found for "GET /"` Being a complete beginner I have no idea what this is. I believe it is some kind of response type, although I'm not sure. **On the other hand if I use `localhost:8000/test` It seems to be working fine, I get my webpage with a message saying that it was just a prank bro :)** Is this how it is supposed to be in symfony? It really messes up with my brain, so if it is fine, can someone explain me why plain `localhost:8000` URL gives me 404 error? Thank you!

Comment: you didn't set a route for the default/home page of your site, just for /test

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take note of the comment above `numberAction`:

```
/**
* @Route("/test")
*/
```

That implies to me that there is a route set up for `localhost:8000/test` which will execute the `numberAction` method.

You need to create a method that will be your home page, and then create a route for `/` which will run your new method. Then when you visit `localhost:8000`, your new method will be executed.

See the [Symphony documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/routing.html) for details on how to set up routes.

Comment: Thank you very much! It was a stupid question after I read your answer. So basically, I just have to write the same method lets say, and instead of specifying `/test` route, I should have plain `/`